# Could you help to edit the json, I'm a new beginner with python. Thank you

Tags: python, json

I need to edit some json config, in order save my time, i want to use the python to edit it automatically, but the the data is complex for me, could you help me .

```
tes={
'key':1, 'Test':45, 'name':'Google',
'list':[{
    'nameinlist':'name1',
    'age':23,
    'country':'LA',
    'parent':{'name':'World'},
    'zipcodeindic':[23,45,66]
    }]
}
```

I want to modify the

```
'nameinlist':'name1'->'nameinlist':'name2'
'parent':{'name':'World'} ->'parent':{'name':'World2'}
'zipcodeindic':[23,45,66]->'zipcodeindic':[23,33,66]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please checkout basic python tutorials on how to load json, modify dictionaries, write distionaries to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tes['list'][0]['nameinlist']='name2'
tes['list'][0]['parent']={'name':'World2'}
tes['list'][0]['zipcodeindic']=[23,33,66]
```

Comment: Thank you, i forget the tes['list'][0]['nameinlist'] index[0], so i failured.